# How to get parameter come after '#' in Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, url, parameters, cgi

How can we fetch the value of folders from below mentioned url:

```
http://my.indiamart.com/cgi/​my-enquiries.mp#folders=1
```

I've tried CGI object, %ENV variable and so many things, but still not been able to get it.

Please suggest..

Comment: See http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

Answer (score 15):

You can't, the browser interprets the fragment (`#folders=1`) without sending it to the server. So if `http://my.indiamart.com/cgi/​my-enquiries.mp` is your script, then it will never see the `#folders=1` part of the URL as the browser won't send it. If you need the fragment on the server then you'll have to change it to a CGI parameter:

```
http://my.indiamart.com/cgi/​my-enquiries.mp?folders=1
```

or embed it in the URL path, something like one of these:

```
http://my.indiamart.com/cgi/​my-enquiries.mp/1
http://my.indiamart.com/cgi/​my-enquiries.mp/folders=1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, # is recognized by JavaScript only,
apache will ignore this, that's the reason it does not contains any value in ENV variable.

You can use JavaScript: `window.location.hash` to capture this hash value.

Comment: Apache doesn't ignore `#`. Apache doesn't receive `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Only with javascript.
You can use something like that to redirect to another script

```
<script>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
if(window.location.hash) {                                                                                                                                                                                         
  var str = window.location.hash.substring(1);                                                                                                                                                                     
  window.location.href = 'http://other_script.pl?param=' + str;
}                                                                                                                
</script>
```